# What phase of matter is salt when dissolved in water?

Tags: physical-chemistry, phase

Being an ionic solid, salt is very susceptible to being torn apart by the polar molecules of water. Inside the water, salt exists as sodium and chlorine anions; **but what state of matter is it in?**
 My instinct tells me it is in a solid state, as salt's melting point is *800°C*, but it sure doesn't really act like a solid.

EDIT: I think I ought to rephrase, I mean what state of matter are the individual sodium and chlorine ions inside the water.

Comment: It's simply liquid solution! I have no idea why tou'd think otherwise

Comment: The salt is liquid? Really? At room temperature?

Comment: Phase is macroscopic - "state of matter are the individual sodium and chlorine ions inside the water" has no sense when salt is dissolving it simply becomes part of liquid mixture - that's it.

Comment: Could you turn that into an answer and provide references? @Mithoron

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/308/what-is-the-difference-between-melting-and-dissolving may answer it even better